# Insert additional into a String

Tags: java, string, kotlin

I have this

```
var message = "You purchased $name on $date"
```

And also have this method that will replace every instance of the $ sign with the word that comes right next to it e.g $ date will be `querySnapshot.get(date)`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message  = "You purchased $name on $date";
    String[] arr = message.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String s = arr[i];
        if (s.contains("$")) {
            arr[i] = "+ querySnapshot.get(" + "\"" + s.substring(1) + "\"" + ")";
        }
    }

    System.out.println(String.join(" ", arr));

}
```

This prints: "   You purchased + querySnapshot.get("name") on + querySnapshot.get("date")  "

Now in order to enable Kotlin to add the dynamic data into it, i need to add ${} in that it should become ${querySnapshot.get(date)}

Can someone help me modify that code, please?

What I need looks like this:

```
"   You purchased + ${ querySnapshot.get("name") }  on + ${querySnapshot.get("date") } "
```

Comment: Arvind Kumar Avinash, am posting this as a new question to build up on the last one

Comment: `Now in order to enable Kotlin to add the dynamic data into it, i need to add ${}` It doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "You purchased $name on $date";
        String[] arr = message.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            String s = arr[i];
            if (s.contains("$")) {
                arr[i] = "+ ${querySnapshot.get(" + "\"" + s.substring(1) + "\"" + ")}";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.join(" ", arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
You purchased + ${querySnapshot.get("name")} on + ${querySnapshot.get("date")}
```